# How To Disable Grid and its children in React js MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I Want to Disable Grid (MUI Component) (and its Children) in React js .

and also , I Want to know how to Disable any Container and it's items in React js! (No matter what kind of children it has)

ex:

```
 <Grid
       item
       disabled  //And any other options
       xs={12}
       md={6}
       spacing={1}
       style={{ padding: '5px' }}>
       <CmpDateTimePicker
         label="from"
         value={this.props.from_timestamp}
         onChange={(from_timestamp) => 
             this.props.OnFromPeriodChanged(from_timestamp)}
         dir={dir}
         intl={intl}
         preSelect={lastMonthDate}
         />
  </Grid>
```

Thanks for your Help! :)

Comment: Please, include details about your goal, describe expected and actual results and include any error messages as text. Then show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We Can disable Element via `pointer-events: none` property.

js file:

```
     <Grid
       item
       className={this.state.isDisabled ? "container-disabled" : "container"}
       xs={12}
       md={6}
       spacing={1}
       style={{ padding: '5px' }}>
       <CmpDateTimePicker
         label="from"
         value={this.props.from_timestamp}
         onChange={(from_timestamp) => 
             this.props.OnFromPeriodChanged(from_timestamp)}
         dir={dir}
         intl={intl}
         preSelect={lastMonthDate}
         />
  </Grid>
```

css file:

```
.container-disabled{
   pointer-events: none;
}

.container{
  /* some styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The disabled prop is not available on every MUI component, but instead you can conditionally render a component by using a simple if statement or ternary operator.

Since you give no context for the above code, I can't directly give you an example, but I can give examples for the two cases I spoke about above.

You can use an if statement like:

```
if(<conditional>){
 return <Grid>...</Grid>
}

return <div></div>
```

With this code your component will only render what is in the if statement when your conditional is true.

Another way is to use a ternary:

```
return (
 <div>
   {<conditional>?<Grid>
   ...
   </Grid>:""}
 </div>
)
```

You can use this inside of jsx to only conditionally render a certain component.